# Dirección de la Base de Datos (path)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

No sé en qué directorio está la base de datos de SQlite (no la veo por ningún lado) y quiero sacar su dirección (donde está), he utilizado esta sentencia:

```
String pathDB = getDatabasePath("nombreBD.db").toString();
```

Pero me sale en rojo `getDatabasePath`, es como si no existiera.
Se supone que `pathDB`  debe de tener la dirección completa de donde está la base de dato.

¿Cómo puedo obtenerlo si no se dónde está, pero sé su nombre?

Gracias

---

Tengo importada la libreria

```
import android.content.Context;
```

Y la llamada esta dentro de un Fragment.

He utilizado esta funcion:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public void backupdDatabase(){
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        String packageName  = "com.delgado.valhondo.fsmerida";
        String sourceDBName = "fsmerida";
        String targetDBName = "fsmerida";
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            Date now = new Date();
         //   String currentDBPath = "data/" + packageName + "/databases/" + sourceDBName;
            String currentDBPath = packageName + "/databases/" + sourceDBName;
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm");
            String backupDBPath = targetDBName + dateFormat.format(now) + ".db";

            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            Log.i("backup","backupDB=" + backupDB.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.i("backup","sourceDB=" + currentDB.getAbsolutePath());

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Backup", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Pero me dice que no encuentra el fichero de la base de datos:

sourceDB=/data/com.delgado.valhondo.fsmerida/databases/fsmerida

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/com.delgado.valhondo.fsmerida/databases/fsmerida (No such file or directory)

Por eso queria saber donde esta realmente por que no la veo en mi Telefono.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la jerarquía de clases de la clase en la que estás ejecutando esa sentencia?. El método `getDatabasePath` está definido en la clase `android.content.Context`, por lo que si lo llamas de esa manera, tu clase tiene que heredar de forma directa o indirecta de la clase `Context`.

Comment: has usado el using apropiado al principio?

Comment: Según lo que dices tu clase es hija de `Fragment`. Pero `Fragment` no es hija de `Context`, por lo que no no encuentra el método `getDatabasePath`. No es suficiente con que tengas importada la clase `Context`. Por eso te sale en rojo en el IDE. Fragment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html?hl=es Context: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener la dirección de la base de datos en base a su nombre mediante:

```
//Obtiene ruta de base de datos origen.
String pathDB = getDatabasePath(<NOMBRE_DATABASE>).toString();
```

**si marca en rojo es porque seguramente no te encuentras en una Activity ya que este método necesita el contexto**,

**Si te encuentras en un `Fragment` puedes usar `getActivity()` como contexto**:

```
//Obtiene ruta de base de datos origen.
String pathDB = getActivity().getDatabasePath(<NOMBRE_DATABASE>).toString();
```

---

También puedes enviar el contexto al llamar a tu método, ejemplo:

```
public static String rutaDatabase(Context ctx){
    String pathDB = ctx.getDatabasePath(<NOMBRE_DATABASE>).toString();
   return pathDB 
}
```

de esta forma llamarías el método

```
String ruta = rutaDatabase(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Me ha servido de mucho. ya hece bien tanto la copia como la restauracion.

Comment: Excelente @FernandoDelgadoFernandez , recuerda marcar como solución las respuestas que ayuden a solucionar la problemática, revisa [tour], saludos.